# How to fix "Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations" error in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-to-speech, grpc

I was implementing the Google Text-to-Speech API and i need to put the credentials in it by using the `Channel` class.

But when i do the `credential.ToChannelCredentials()` method the error `Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations` appears

I looked at the path the error throw to me and i verefied that the method try to reach de `grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll` inside the project bin folder, but the file is at `C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\grpc.core\1.18.0\runtimes\win\native`

To test, i tried to copy the file from that path directely in bin and it worked, but i know that is not right

My code:

```cs
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(MyJSON).CreateScoped(TextToSpeechClient.DefaultScopes);
    var channel = new Channel(TextToSpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials()); // trow the error here
    TextToSpeechClient client = TextToSpeechClient.Create(channel);
```

I expect the program get the right path of the .dll, but is trying to get from folder bin of my project

`grpc.core` version *1.18.0*

Comment: what's your platform and project type?

Comment: I use Windows 10 and the project type is a Website project using webforms if is that what you asked for

Comment: In that case this is a known issue. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12570

Comment: Ow, i didn't know this issue, thank you for your comment